# Checking if a instagram image is private

Tags: api, privacy, instagram

Say I have the URL to an image, http://instagr.am/p/xxxxxxxx/, how can I check if the image is set to private or not from a webpage? Is there some API that I can use?

I need this since I have a bunch of Instagram images that I show on my page, but I want to remove the link to them if they become private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to see if a specific image was private or not, so instead i save the AuthorID of the image. If this author has a private profile i will get an exception when trying to get the user information, and if i get an exception, then i know i can remove the link to the image.

This is my powershell-code i use:

```
try
{
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<InsertAuthorID>/?client_id=xxxx";
}
catch [Exception]
{
    # Remove Image
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find if the image has been removed having image page url such as http://instagr.am/p/xxxxxxxx/ ? i want to find those images that got removed or deleted by user so i stop displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GET relationship endpoint.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-id/relationship
```

This endpoint returns a BOOL value "target_user_is_private".